# Python .format() added to an url but throws a KeyError

Tags: python

I want to add a variable with .format() to an url but python throws a KeyError.

The error I get:

```py
KeyError: '"page"'
```

I have added .format() and {} to the url see the url below. At the end of url .format() is added.

```py
url with .format() / {"page":{}}'.format(valuetest)
url = 'https://nl.soccerway.com/a/block_competition_matches_summary?block_id=page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5&callback_params={"page":"-1","block_service_id":"competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary","round_id":"50855","outgroup":"","view":"2","competition_id":"34"}&action=changePage&params={"page":{}}'.format(valuetest)

original url:
url = 'https://nl.soccerway.com/a/block_competition_matches_summary?block_id=page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5&callback_params={"page":"-1","block_service_id":"competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary","round_id":"50855","outgroup":"","view":"2","competition_id":"34"}&action=changePage&params={"page":1}'
```

Below is what I want in a simple example:

```py
valuetest = '1'
urltest = 'https://www.testing.com{}'.format(valuetest)
print(urltest)
```

result: https://www.testing.com1

How can I create the url so I can add a variable to the url?

Comment: Please provide a full example that we can actually run.  This code has undefined variable references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *escape* any braces that are not part of a replacement field.

```
url = 'https://nl.soccerway.com/a/block_competition_matches_summary?block_id=page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5&callback_params={{"page":"-1","block_service_id":"competition_summary_block_competitionmatchessummary","round_id":"50855","outgroup":"","view":"2","competition_id":"34"}}&action=changePage&params={{"page":{}}}'
```

---

https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print literal curly braces and use format, you have to double them.

So it should be `params={{"page":{}}}` instead of `params={"page":{}}`. The same with `callback_params`.